# How can I save a document from web page on server side?

Tags: python, apache, server

I'm using apache and python to run my web pages. But when I try to save even a txt file generated on the fly, the file is not saved.

def save(req):

```
try:  
    fe1=req.form['fe1']  
    fe2=req.form['fe2']  
    file=open("file.txt",'w')  
    file.write("%s %s" %(fe1,fe2))  
    file.close()  
except KeyError:  
    fe1=''  
    fe2=''  
view="""
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>

        </head>
        <body>
            <form method=post action="#">
                <input type='text' id='fe1'></input>
                <input type='text' id='fe2'></input>
                <input type='submit'>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
""".format(**locals())

return (view)
```

After I submi the form I get this:

`Mod_python error: "PythonHandler mod_python.publisher"`

`Traceback (most recent call last):`

`File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 399, in HandlerDispatch

    result = obj(req)`
  `File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 222, in handler`
  `published = publish_object(req, object)`

`File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/publisher.py", line 446, in publish_object`
    `return publish_object(req, util.apply_fs_data(obj, req.form, req=req))`

`File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/mod_python/util.py", line 642,` `in apply_fs_data`
    `return object(**args)`

`File "<string>", line 5, in save`

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file.txt'`

Comment: Please add a [mcve] of your code

Comment: I solved using this at the beginning :                                            `import os`
`def save(req):`
 `mydir=r'/dir1/dir2'`
 `os.chdir(mydir)`
 try: